# Cake PHP Login Element

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

my problem is the following:

i would like to use a login element instead of a login view.
so i can use the login in my default.ctp... i want the user to have the possibility to login from every page. It should be a sort of dropdown menu.

How can i tell my controller to use the element and get the element data and not the view anymore?

My LoginsController login function:

```
function login()
{
    $this->set('headline','Melden Sie sich an...');

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if($this->Auth->login())
        {
            //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            $this->Session->setFlash('Ihr Login war erfolgreich!');
        }
        else
        {
          //  $this->Session->setFlash('Ihre Email/Passwort ist falsch!' . ' ' . $this->request->data['Login']['email'] . ' ' . $this->request->data['Login']['password']);
            $this->Session->setFlash('Ihre Email/Passwort ist falsch!');
        }
    }
    $this->render('logins/login');
}
```

My View/Element:

```
<aside id="left">

<div class="whitebox einloggen">
    <div class="rahmen">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div class="inside">

  <?php              echo $this->Html->para(null,'Sind Sie bereits als Nutzer registriert?');



    echo $this->Form->create('Login', array('action' => 'login'));

    echo $this->Form->input('email', array ('label' => false, 'type'=>'text','class'=>'text', 'value'=>'E-Mail','id'=>'LoginEmail', 'onfocus'=>"resetinput(this);", 'onBlur'=>"fillinput(this);"));
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array ('label' => false, 'type'=>'text','class'=>'text', 'value'=>'Passwort','id'=>'LoginPassword', 'onfocus'=>"resetinputpw(this);", 'onBlur'=>"fillinput(this);"));
    echo $this->Form->end(array('label'=>'Einloggen','class' => 'button long','type' => 'submit','name'=>'submit'));

    echo $this->Html->para('forgetpw', $this->Html->link('Passwort vergessen?', array('controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'forgotpwd'), array('label' => false, 'class' => 'forgetpw', 'title'=>'Passwort vergessen')));

    echo $this->Html->link('', array('controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'fblogin'), array('class' => 'facebook-button', 'title'=>'Mit Facebook einloggen'));
    ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call the element in the default.ctp like this:

```
<?php    echo $this->element('/logins/login'); ?>
```

Its always complaining about missing the login view...

If this isnt a good practise, please teach me otherwise ;-)

Sorry for my bad english and thanks!

Comment: Double check that the file exists in App/Views/Elements/logins/login.ctp and that it's a ctp extension and make sure you remove the beginning "/" in your statement. $this->element('logins/login');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the view in the controller?

If the element is included in default.ctp, adding

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

in place of

```
$this->render('logins/login');
```

in your login controller will stop the Login Controller trying to specifically render the view.

You will need to place your element in the Elements directory (under 'Views') and then update your code in default.ctp to be

```
<?php echo $this->element('login'); ?>
```

Also, using the cakephp way of setting up the links and forms may help you in the element.

For full guidance for the form, try here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

For how to do links the cake way, try: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for you fast reply.

Im not using the Cake HTML-Helper because i got a custom HTML template with custom css and javascript.
I dont know how to implement it otherwise than using normal HTML in the Views. Using the cake way of setting up forms never applys my design the way it should look.


How can i disable the login view in the controller?

Should i call the "$this->autoRender = false;" directly under 
"$this->element('/logins/login');"?

Comment: Hi there, you may want to try using this->Html->link for your links as a worst case in case you have to change your controller paths.

Comment: To disable the view, replace this->render('logins/login') with $this->autoRender = false. You shouldn't need to touch the code in your default.ctp

Comment: Adding $this->autoRender = false; to my default.ctp shows me a blank site.

If i use the element, and try to submit the login it shows this error:
Error: The view for LoginsController::login() was not found.

I understand the error, but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: My comment probably wasn't clear enough, the reason you're seeing the missing login view is probably the $this->render('/logins/login') in your login controller. I have just noticed your syntax is probably wrong for the element too. The element must be placed in 'Views' -> 'Elements' and can then be accessed with $this->element('login');

Comment: How to mix the this->Html->link with my css?

Thanks a lot for your time :-)

Comment: echo $this->Html->link('Passwort vergessen?', array('controller' => 'login', 'action' => 'forgotpwd'), array('class' => 'yourclasshere', 'title' => 'Passwort vergessen'));

Comment: But, i still cant get it working to change my view to a element...

When i add autorender=false at the end of my login function in the loginscontroller, i always get a blank page.

What i want to do is just have a login element i can use everywhere.
no like the view, that always redirects to logins/login...

Comment: I set up the view now in cake way mostly.
How can i set up the divs and should i do it?

Comment: OK - add the element to default.ctp using $this->elements('login') making sure that login.ctp is in your 'View' -> 'Elements' folder.

Comment: Remove the autorender-false from your Login controller. Make sure your form action points to your logins controller